# Android managedQuery() IllegalArgumentException on opening returned URI path to a single contact

Tags: android, path, uri, contacts, illegalargumentexception

I'm having trouble with a tutorial application from Professional Android 2 Application Development. I'm developing for android 2.3, and it seems like the code has changed a good bit in revisions.

Basically I have two activities, one that launches the other, to get a list of contacts and then to return the contact chosen back to the first activity which will then display it on screen, I know android has something that does this already, but I'm trying to learn here :p

All communication between the activities is handled using intents. The first activity starts up the other activity fine, I can pick a contact and it returns it to the first activity. It runs `onReturnActivity()` all fine. But when I try to create a cursor(Using `managedQuery()`) in `onReturnActivity()` to open the single returned contacts database entry, everything goes pearshaped and I get an IllegalArgumentException.

That returned URI path is: content://com.android.contacts/contacts15 (Or another number).

The Error is:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo { 
            who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { 
            dat=content://com.android.contacts/contacts15 }} 
 to activity {com.paad.contactPicker/com.paad.contactPicker.ContactPickerTester}:
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
    URI: content://com.android.contacts/contacts15, 
    calling user: com.paad.contactPicker, 
    calling package:com.paad.contactPicker
```

Creating the cursor in the other activity works okay though, so the only things I can think (With my very limited knowledge of Android) is that it's a problem with the uri path or with the entry returned from the other activity not containing anything. But I'm more inclined to believe it's the first.

All permissions set and I can access the contacts database in the other activity fine.

Would really appreciate some help on this, I've been stuck for the past 2 days :/

EDIT

Here's calling the second activity:

```
public void onClick(View _view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Uri.parse("content://android.provider.ContactsContract")) ;
                startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT) ;
            }
```

I don't actually use the URI I pass in to this Intent though, I have it hardcoded into the second activity as this:

```
final Uri data = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI ;
```

And here's where I call managedQuery() the first time (where it works):

```
 final Cursor c = managedQuery(data, null, null, null, null) ;
```

Here's the onReturn Activity:
    public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resCode, Intent data) {
         super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resCode, data) ;

```
     switch(reqCode) {
        case(PICK_CONTACT) : {
            if(resCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Uri contactData = data.getData() ;
                Cursor c = managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null) ;
                c.moveToFirst() ;
                String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("DISPLAY_NAME")) ;
                TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2) ;
                tv.setText(name) ;
            }
        }
        break ;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Can you post code snippets on how you call the second activity, the onReturnActivity() method, as well as your managedQuery code.

Comment: Posted above as an edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm almost positive that the URI is bad. I'm pretty sure there should be a slash before the number 15, like this: content://com.android.contacts/contacts/15. I currently can't test it out for you though. I can't discern much else from the code; sorry, but if you can figure this part out, I think you will fix the problem. It is probably how your second activity is returning the URI. Hope this helps.

Comment: It worked! Stuck for so long on such a simple problem, that's my inexperience for you.. Thanks a million for your help :)